# is there such a thing as big/little endian for bits?

Tags: bit, endianness

We all know about endianness for bytes, but is there such a thing as endiannes for bits?

I got into a conversation with a colleague at work about this and he said that there is no such thing. He said it is not endianness, it is bit ordering. However during my college years, I distinctly remember some of the professors referring to bit ordering as big/little endianness.

So here is my question:

Is there such a thing as endiannes for bits?

Comment: is there such a thing as alphabetical ordering inside a single character?

Comment: I recall coming across a compiler which referred to bit-field structures in reverse order (i.e., MSB comes first). If I'm not mistaken, then it was a compiler for PPC (which happens to be BE architecture). But it is indeed, as your friend suggested, a simple matter of bit-ordering. You cannot use the same claim for the order of bytes in different architectures (i.e., LE vs BE), since it is more than a "compiler interpretation" issue in that case - the data is "physically" ordered differently in memory.

Comment: @barakmanos Can you elaborate more on this, I don't think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my little-endian bit: 1

Could you please convert it to a big-endian bit?

Either the question doesn't make sense at all, or it has a vacuous answer: the big-endian version of 1 is 1. It is a question of definition whether or not this is nonsensical or pointless. Endianness isn't a useful notion for individual bits.

Comment: BE/LE will also not make any sense for a 1 byte value. For example, 0x0A. Can you give me an LE or BE version of 0x0A?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't, unless you are addressing individual bits (e.g. with the setbit POSIX macro or when using bit access assembler instructions), in which case is is a function of the API or particular instruction, not of the processor architecture.

Endianness matters when you view the same underlying storage with two different views: as an array of bytes and an array of words (and maybe doublewords, quadwords, etc.). You never view most storage as an array of bits, so the "order" in which they are does not matter to you; endianness matters between the different levels at which you can address storage, and given that both files as considered today and the memory in all remotely modern architectures are byte-addressed (with the possibility to address larger entities using byte addresses), the endianness of entities below the byte does not even exist.

That being said, I have seen "endianness" be used in processor architecture description documents to designate the numbering convention used to designate bits in a word.

Comment: I also have seen this usage in some of my communication classes. Sometimes if you want to send your data they will use big-endian or little-endian instead of LSB or MSB.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** there is a similar notion. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bit_endianness):

> **Bit numbering** is a concept similar to endianness, but on a level of bits, not bytes. *Bit endianness* or *bit-level endianness* refers to the transmission order of bits over a serial medium.

This is a very niche area. It only occurs in hardware and even then, it's not a common thing to consider. It only matters for very old serial transmission (think printer ports). Considering byte-level endianness is such a huge topic, using the term *bit endianness* is only going to cause confusion and controversy. Indeed Wikipedia states:

> ... the terms *bit endianness* and *bit-level endianness* **are seldom used**

In a lecture it might be fine to use these terms just to give an explanation but in practice (at work), you should probably avoid using the term endianness at the bit-level.